# Set ToolBar Buttons square and all the same size in JavaFX 2

Tags: java, javafx-2

In the code below I have a ToolBar and I add buttons of various sizes to it. I would like the buttons to be square and all the same size. So basically find the longest width or height from all the buttons, and set all other button widths and height to this size. However, the buttons can change size so I require a binding I think. I can't quite figure it out - anyone know how to do it?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToolBarButtonTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500);

        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();

        Button button1 = new Button("s");
        Button button2 = new Button("ss");
        Button button3 = new Button("sss");

        toolBar.getItems().addAll(button1, button2, button3);

        borderPane.setTop(toolBar);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. This example will use CSS to turn the button shape into a square, and install a validation listener to track layout changes to the buttons and update the widths accordingly.

```
public class SquareButtons extends Application {
@Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    /* Assume these are your toolbar elements */
    final Button[] buttons = new Button[]{
            new Button("Short"),
            new Button("Slightly longer"),
            new Button("Very very very long button")
    };

    /* This would, of course, belong in a style sheet - it turns the buttons square */
    for (Button b : buttons)
        b.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0");

    /* This will set the pref width/height of all your buttons to the maximum of the pref width/height of the larget one */
    final InvalidationListener listener = new InvalidationListener() {
        public void invalidated(final Observable observable) {
            double size = 0;
            for (Button b : buttons) {
                size = Math.max(size, b.prefWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                size = Math.max(size, b.prefHeight(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            }

            for (Button b : buttons) {
                b.setPrefWidth(size);
                b.setPrefHeight(size);
            }
        }
    };

    for (Button b : buttons)
        b.widthProperty().addListener(listener);

    final ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();
    toolbar.getItems().addAll(buttons);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(toolbar);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setWidth(800);
    stage.setHeight(200);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }
}
```

Update: Didn't read question thoroughly enough, see comment.

Comment: I think the OP meant "square" in the sense that the button heights and widths are all the same. Your example would be closer to the intent if you added "b.setPrefHeight(width)" in the same place you set the width in the InvalidationListener. I don't think he meant to make the button corners square.

Comment: You are, of course, right - my bad. I've updated the answer accordingly, although square text buttons are just ugly imho.

Comment: I did mean square as in the width and height are the same size. I was hoping this could be achieved with the binding api however this works perfectly so thanks very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has responded, I'll pass along a partial solution. I'm a noob at JavaFX, but since the parent is responsible for laying out the child nodes, I would derive a modified version of the `ToolBar` class and override some of the layout code. Here's is a modification of your example that works, but is a bit kludgy.

```
package toolbarbuttontest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToolBarButtonTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500);

        Button btn1 = new Button("short");
        Button btn2 = new Button("between");
        Button btn3 = new Button("pretty long");

        SquareButtonToolBar toolBar = new SquareButtonToolBar();
        toolBar.getItems().addAll(btn1, btn2, btn3);

        borderPane.setTop(toolBar);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        toolBar.requestLayout();
    }

    // A derivative of the ToolBar class that will resize all buttons to be
    // the same size (based on the length of the longest button label) and
    // square.
    class SquareButtonToolBar extends ToolBar {

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            double minPrefSize = calculatePrefChildSize();
            for (Node n : getItems()) {
                if (n instanceof Button) {
                    ((Button) n).setPrefWidth(minPrefSize);
                    ((Button) n).setPrefHeight(minPrefSize);
                }
            }
            super.layoutChildren();
        }

        private double calculatePrefChildSize() {
            double minPrefSize = 0.0d;
            for (Node n : getItems()) {
                if (n instanceof Button) {
                    minPrefSize = Math.max(minPrefSize, n.prefWidth(-1));
                }
            }
            return minPrefSize;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The `SquareButtonToolBar` class overrides the layout code by setting the preferred width and height of the buttons to the length of the longest button, thus making all the buttons square and the same size. The kludge is the call to `toolBar.requestLayout()` at the bottom of the `start` method. Without this call, even though the button widths are all shown as desired on program start up, the heights are not displayed correctly until the window is re-sized. Not sure what I'm missing myself. If you find the answer, please post an update.

**UPDATE:** Modified example to a fully working one, but with a nasty kludge.